# Redirect to login.xhtml Page from java code

Tags: redirect, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-webflow

I am trying to redirect to login.xhtml which in flow folder through java code using JSF and Spring Web-flow.
[image]

**Using below code: -  It redirect to below path but not login.xhtml.**

ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
            ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/beas/login");

Error on browser  - The page isn't redirecting properly

**tried NavigationHandler but it also unable to handle the redirect state**

NavigationHandler navigationHandler = facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
//              navigationHandler.handleNavigation(facesContext,null,"/login?faces-redirect=true");

---

Update Info : -

Below is Spring webflow config in which i have define the base-path

[image]

Below is Spring MVC config in that i have define faceletsViewResolver

[image]

Below is security Config xml
[image]

config folder : - 
[image]